# New GCM API Register Unknown Source Error

Tags: android, push-notification, ioexception, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently building an application that uses the new Google Cloud Messaging system. I have a HTTP client server set up on a live environment to allow me to test through my mobile devices, but when ever I try to register with the GCM I keep getting a IOException that states that `gcm.register()` is receiving an Unknown Source stopping me from getting the Registration Id I need to allow my server send messages to my device.

I have checked several times to see if my Sender Id is wrong and I have checked over my manifest as well to see if I have that wrong as well and I cannot seem to find the problem. Looking around also hasn't provided any answer to my problem.

Here is my Log:

```
07-18 11:34:25.487: W/System.err(3093): java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at koodoo.pushtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 11:34:25.497: W/System.err(3093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="koodoo.pushtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="koodoo.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="koodoo.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="koodoo.pushtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="koodoo.pushtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="koodoo.pushtest.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's the error you are getting :

```
java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
```

It means you are calling the register method from the main thread, which is not allowed. You should call it from another thread.

> public static final String ERROR_MAIN_THREAD
>
> GCM methods are blocking. You should not run them in the main thread or in broadcast receivers.
>   Constant Value: "MAIN_THREAD"

Here's a code sample from the [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) :

```
/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Stores the registration id, app versionCode, and expiration time in the 
 * application's shared preferences.
 */
private void registerBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                // using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Save the regid - no need to register again.
                setRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Not work for me, I create a demo from Android Document as you mention above, I create all code from developer site but still I got same IOException...

Answer (score 10):

1.Just create the **GCMHelper** class to get the CGM ID.

```
public final class GCMHelper {

static GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = null;

static Context context= null;

public GCMHelper (Context context)
{
    this.context= context;
}

public String GCMRegister (String SENDER_ID) throws Exception
{
    String regid = "";
    //Check if Play store services are available.
    if(!checkPlayServices())
        throw new Exception("Google Play Services not supported. Please install and configure Google Play Store.");

    if (gcm == null) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    }
    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

    return regid;
}


private static boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

2.Then create **GetGCM()** method in in Activity.

```
//**To avoid java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD**    

 private void GetGCM() {
    
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                 GCMHelper  gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper (
            getApplicationContext());
                String gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister(SENDER_ID);

            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

3.Then call **GetGCM()** method wherever you want.