# Unable to unregister GCM in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to unregister the `GCM` when the user logout. I am using the following code to do it.

```
public void logout(){

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(NewSettings.this);
        try {
            gcm.unregister();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(NewSettings.this,"Problem in logout, try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

This does not unregister the GCM as I am getting an exception in the `logcat` which is like this

```
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister(Unknown Source)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.artqueen.aahaan.Activities.NewSettings.logout(NewSettings.java:157)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.artqueen.aahaan.Activities.NewSettings$7.onClick(NewSettings.java:120)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21173)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
07-14 10:54:20.718  26537-26537/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

**The documentation mentions that**

[image: documentation]

So I also tried to use this

```
 public void logout(){

        InstanceID instanceID  = InstanceID.getInstance(NewSettings.this);
        try {
            instanceID.deleteInstanceID();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(NewSettings.this,"Problem in logout, try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

}

and I am still getting this in the `logcat`

```
07-14 11:02:03.228  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzb(Unknown Source)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.deleteInstanceID(Unknown Source)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.artqueen.aahaan.Activities.NewSettings.logout(NewSettings.java:158)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.artqueen.aahaan.Activities.NewSettings$7.onClick(NewSettings.java:121)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21173)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
07-14 11:02:03.238  31682-31682/com.artqueen.aahaan W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Am I unregistering the `GCM` in the proper way ? Please let me know how can I achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may run `unregister` in `AsyncTask`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721541/new-gcm-api-register-unknown-source-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to run it in a new thread. This fixed my problem. 
Thanks @calvinfly.

```
public void logout(){

        instanceID  = InstanceID.getInstance(NewSettings.this);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    instanceID.deleteInstanceID();
                } catch (Exception bug) {
                    bug.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to unregister the GCM.
GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());

Comment: `gcm.unregister()` was deprecated on May 28, 2015.