# Android GCM InstanceId.getToken() -> java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to implement push notifications in my android app but i'm currently stuck at the point of receiving a token.

I'm using the latest method of "InstanceID" and followed some examples.
I've added the permissions and the services to my Manifest ( and added the code for them aswell ) but whatever i try, i always get the "java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT" error. I've tried different phones, wifi, Lte and 3G but nothing seems to change anything.

I never got to the error saying "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE". Only stuck at this one.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<receiver
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="de.company.appname" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
  android:name="de.company.gcm.ModuleGCMListenerService"
  android:exported="false" >
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
  android:name="de.company.gcm.ModuleInstanceIDListenerService"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

InstanceID call:

```
try 
{
  token = instanceID.getToken(
            senderId,
            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, 
            null);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

instanceID.getId() is working.

```
W/InstanceID/Rpc: No response android.os.ConditionVariable@129d5713
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
W/System.err:   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Take look at this repo [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android) and the source which related to `InstanceID.getToken()` is [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/399e88c1ef5bb95395b6392f9061e45b2fb5d49a/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/logic/InstanceIdHelper.java).

Comment: Thanks, though i've already been through all the google examples and several other pages. None of them gave me any clue what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: Have u just clone the repo and tried yourself on your IDE without your code ? You can make it a try

Comment: I'm currently having this same issue... it was working perfectly before

Comment: If you are using WIFI try turning it off and used your mobile Network, it worked for me.

Comment: @bjiang i haven't cloned the repo but i've copied the nescesarry files into my project. But from my understanding it's not a missing file or service, since i can see the Logcat until just 1 line above or am i wrong here?

Comment: @PaulOkeke As i said in my question, i've tried different phones on different networks ( wifi and mobile data ). It didn't change anything.

Comment: I noticed that you have no service for registration in your manifest, could you show some more of the code you are using to do the registration?

Comment: you have putted your Project Configuration JSON file in your project or not ?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I didn't seem to be the problem. What service were you talking about?

Comment: @DhavalkumarSolanki No i haven't. It's kind of like a module programming, so i'm passing the required senderId to this method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem when searching for similar errors at the same position in the code.

[New GCM API Register Unknown Source Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721541/new-gcm-api-register-unknown-source-error)

In this case the Error "MAIN_THREAD" is indeed a bit more obvious.

So it was because the InstanceId.getToken() can't be called in the Main Thread.

Though it didn't work with the `new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()` method as suggested in the Google Github Examples.

I had to use

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //code
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Does not matter The operation need to be out of the Main Thread , it could be in Async or new Thread